# How to synchronously execute a function using chrome.storage.local.get and XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
function get_pps_params(callback)
{
    var ppsParams = null;
    chrome.storage.local.get(['ppsParams'], function(result) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(result))
        {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", CLOUD_SERVER + 'get_pps_params', true);
            oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                console.log("Got pps params compressed!");
                ppsParams = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
                chrome.storage.local.set({ppsParams: _arrayBufferToBase64(ppsParams)});
            };

            oReq.send();
        }
        else
        {
            ppsParams = _base64ToArrayBuffer(result.ppsParams);
        }
        callback(ppsParams);
    });
}
```

I am using the above function to retrieve certain parameters from local storage and if they are not present in local storage then the `chrome.storage.local.get` callback sends request for the data to server. This makes the whole `get_pps_params` asynchronous(obviously). So how do I  make it execute synchronously ? I read something about jQuery.Deferred but did not understand it.

Currently `callback(ppsParams)` gives me null if the request is sent to server because of the async nature of XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah I had only asked that question previosuly but now the situation is somewhat different from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar solution to last time

```
function get_pps_params(callback)
{
    var ppsParams = null;
    chrome.storage.local.get(['ppsParams'], function(result) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(result))
        {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", CLOUD_SERVER + 'get_pps_params', true);
            oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                console.log("Got pps params compressed!");
                ppsParams = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
                chrome.storage.local.set({ppsParams: _arrayBufferToBase64(ppsParams)});
                callback(ppsParams); // added this line
            };

            oReq.send();
        }
        else
        {
            ppsParams = _base64ToArrayBuffer(result.ppsParams);
            callback(ppsParams); // moved this line
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah that should work, though I wanted to know about jquery.Deferred more. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know that I'd bother with jquery.Deferred, either. Even if I wanted to use the jQuery API instead of native XHR, I would use the success handler.

Comment: if you rewrite this to use jquery.Deferred, you wouldn't use a callback, you'd return a promise and call this using `get_pps_params().then( ...`

Comment: dont use jquery use standard js promise.

Comment: @ZigMandel - as long as you have a decent browser, IE need not apply

Comment: then there is a polifill for older ones isnt it? not worth learning the jquery one when they are different from the now standard

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jquery.Deferred

```
function get_pps_params()
{
    var ppsParams = null;
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();
    chrome.storage.local.get(['ppsParams'], function(result) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(result))
        {
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", CLOUD_SERVER + 'get_pps_params', true);
            oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                console.log("Got pps params compressed!");
                ppsParams = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
                chrome.storage.local.set({ppsParams: _arrayBufferToBase64(ppsParams)});
                def.resolve(ppsParams);
            };

            oReq.send();
        }
        else
        {
            ppsParams = _base64ToArrayBuffer(result.ppsParams);
            def.resolve(ppsParams);
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

instead of

```
get_pps_params(someFunc);
```

use

```
get_pps_params().then(someFunc);
```

> You can achieve the same result using proper Promise - comes standard with any decent browser, or use a polyfill for non-decent browsers

```
function get_pps_params()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var ppsParams = null;
        chrome.storage.local.get(['ppsParams'], function(result) {
            if ($.isEmptyObject(result))
            {
                var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                oReq.open("GET", CLOUD_SERVER + 'get_pps_params', true);
                oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

                oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                    console.log("Got pps params compressed!");
                    ppsParams = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
                    chrome.storage.local.set({ppsParams: _arrayBufferToBase64(ppsParams)});
                    resolve(ppsParams);
                };

                oReq.send();
            }
            else
            {
                ppsParams = _base64ToArrayBuffer(result.ppsParams);
                resolve(ppsParams);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

once again you'd use the

```
get_pps_params().then(someFunc);
```

method